# How to fix exception: " System.IO.FileNotFoundException" after run published WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, mscorlib

I published a `WPF` app. But when I setup and ran it  in different computer, there is  nothing display in the desktop. I tried to use `EventViewer` app and then explore some errors(I also tried in my computer, It worked OK with no exception and error): 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC9gc.png)

> Source(.Net runtime) have 
>   Error:

```
 Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.String)
   at DevExpress.Utils.AssemblyHelper.GetAssembly(System.String)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Theme.GetAssembly()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Theme.get_Assembly()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemedElementsDictionary.GetThemeAssembly(System.String)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemedElementsDictionary.ForceThemeKeysLoading(System.String)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemeManager.ChangeTheme(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, System.String)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemeManager.ThemeNamePropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemeManager.DevExpress.Xpf.Utils.Themes.IThemeManager.SetThemeName(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.String)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Utils.Themes.GlobalThemeHelper.SetGlobalTheme(System.Windows.FrameworkElement)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Utils.Themes.GlobalThemeHelper.AssignApplicationThemeName(System.Windows.FrameworkElement)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Utils.Themes.GlobalThemeHelper.EnumerateSafe(System.Windows.WindowCollection, System.Action`1<System.Windows.Window>)
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Utils.Themes.GlobalThemeHelper.SetApplicationWindows()
   at DevExpress.Xpf.Utils.Themes.GlobalThemeHelper.SetWindowsApplicationThemeName()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Thr
```

> Source Application have Error:

```
 Faulting application name: WpfApplication5.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5b491a6b
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.16299.309, time stamp: 0xd3aa915c
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x001008f2
Faulting process id: 0x2ffc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d41bc5ee509362
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\WPF5\WPF5\WpfApplication5.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
```

I continued in one more computer. There was a dialog my app `"Has stopped working"` display, when clicked in detail button . It showed me exception occured with: `mscorlib.dll`

I wasted a week to search information to fix it. But I could not  solve it. Thank to Good bro to help me!

Comment: You need to capture enough of the stack trace to see where you are invoking the failing code path. Looking at the stack I suspect you have a missing dependency triggered by reflection loading another assembly.

Comment: `DevExpress.Xpf.Utils.Themes.GlobalThemeHelper.SetWindowsApplicationThemeName()` something to do with Themes...

Comment: Install WinDbg from [Windows Debugging Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/) on the affected PCs, load [SOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension) and run your application from within WinDbg. In WinDbg, you usually can get more information about about the exception. E.g. `!pe` lets you print details about the last .NET exception. Alternatively, save the crash dump and open it in Visual Studio on your dev PC.

Comment: @Richard I captured screen. I don't know  I do it correctly flow your mean

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh I just design some report use dev. I don't know about Themes... that you said in my code. so sorry for not enough knowledge

Comment: @FrankM Ok. I'm installing it and do all things flow you said

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some absolute path on the code, i.e: "C:/Users/X/Desktop/ ..."
Try to change absolute paths with relative paths.

Comment: I used relativity path like: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Basedirectory